# Searching in ajax does not return result with spaces

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

After clicking the search button in my page it typically outputs the result of the query. however i have a problem with regards to conditions where the value of the field has  a white space. so what i am doing is to trim the string and look it up in the database using LIKE statement.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btnsearch').click(function(e) {
        $("#content0 #sub_cont0").load("view/search.php?document=<?php echo $_GET['document']; ?>&stat=<?php echo $_GET['stat']?>&ac=<?php echo $_GET['ac']; ?>&fac=<?php echo $_GET['fac']; ?>&val=" + $("#txtsearch").val() + "&model=<?php echo trim($_GET['model']);?>");
        $(".tblmodellist").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

example i will search for the word "casing". under the category model = "Test Model". When this is queried in the database, it does not output anything using this query. 
NOTE: in the above script, I trimmed the model so the output will be "Test" only. But still it does not return my expected result set.

```
  $sql =    "SELECT * FROM $db WHERE (
    FileName LIKE '%" . $id . "%' OR
    $title LIKE '%" . $id . "%' OR
    $no LIKE '%" . $id . "%' )
    AND (Stat = '$stat' AND Model LIKE '%".$model."%')
    ";
```

What do you think is the problem in my ajax request? I have found earlier during my debug that when I put the $_GET['model'] in the center, it cuts down the query resulting in a NULL value, that is the reason why i put it in the end of the line.

Comment: I hope you are sanitizing your inputs

Comment: **you will be hacked**

Comment: i have another class handling that, for now I am just narrowing the problem. =D

Comment: Why do you have **php and javascript all mixed up**.. this is not a good practise!!

Comment: just doing separately.one by one.

Comment: Can you take a look at what `$_GET['model']` looks like directly? Chances are you are in need of a `urldecode($_GET['model'])` in order to get the whitespace back.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
    $urlParams = array('document', 'stat', 'ac', 'fac', 'model');
    $urlQuery = array();
    foreach($urlParams as $urlParam)
        $urlQuery[ $urlParam ] = $_GET[$urlParam];
?>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnsearch').click(function(e) {
        $("#content0 #sub_cont0").load("view/search.php?<?php echo http_build_query($urlQuery); ?>&val=" + $("#txtsearch").val());
        $(".tblmodellist").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```